# Using WP8 Emulator without Windows 8 Pro or Actual Device

Tags: windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, windows-phone-8-emulator

Is there any way to do this by running a WP8 emulator in a virtual machine? I would really like to publish WP8 apps but I need to do some testing and don't want to pay to upgrade to the pro version of windows. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no solution for this. You have to have a emulator or a device to test the app and testing on a device is mandatory now. There used to be Nokia Remote Device Access but it is deprecated now. http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Windows Phone emulator needs hardware virtualization features (enabled in BIOS) and only the pro version is capable of using them (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions search for hyper-v).

You can find some reference here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx